# EMR - disable any application configuration using the application configuration json

Tags: amazon-emr, hue

In the EMR configuration, how to disable any application feature using the configuration json object? Such as disabling any '[[interpreters]]' in the hue configuration, can be done by commenting the same on the hue.ini file. With the application configuration json, how could we accomplish the same?

For amending/overriding any config for example with hue.ini, steps are shown on AWS doc as https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/hue-ldap.html.

Wondering if there is an option to disable any feature using this way instead of directly editing the hue.ini file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.